# For each loop to display input arrays set

Tags: php

Html:

```
<input type="date" name="employment_companyname[]">
    <input type="date" name="employment_datefrom[]">
    <input type="date" name="employment_dateto[]">
    <input type="date" name="employment_mainduties[]">
```

Php:

```
foreach( $employment_companyname as $m => $employmentcompanyname ) {
    echo $employment_datefrom[$m];
    echo $employment_dateto[$m];
    echo $employmentcompanyname;
    foreach( $employment_mainduties[$m] as $n =>$employmentmainduties) {
        echo $employmentmainduties;
    }
}
```

Job1

> Date from - Date to
>   Company Name
>   List of duties unique to this company name (depending on how many you have added)

Job2

> Date from - Date to
>   Company Name
>   List of duties unique to this company name (depending on how many you have added)

Job3 etc.

It currently prints out like:

> Job1
>   Unique duties to Job1 and Job2
>
> Job2
>   Unique duties to Job1 and Job2

Rather than:

> Job1
>   Unique duties to Job1
>
> Job2
>   Unique duties to Job2

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: Read [ask]. In its current state the question is not clear. What do you want to get? And what doesn't work?

Comment: whoops, i meant to add it has to print out the text below the code - currently it would print out like:
Job1
List of duties unique to job1 and job2

Job2
List of duties unique to job1 and job2

Comment: Please update your code snippet, the PHP is not well wrapped in php tags. Please first test the code before you post it.

Comment: We don't have all the information. Please provide the complete HTML form (with the PHP loop you have to repeat some inputs), and example input and output. The current output you have provided does not match with the code you provide (there is no code that produces " and" for example). Please make your question as clear and exact as possible.